# Extract column name row wise which contains a specific value pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I want to get column name row wise where the value isn't "Do".

```
   A  B  C  D

1 Do  1 All Do

2  5  2 NA Do

3 1  3 NA NA

4 Do  Do  Do  Do
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C  D Column_names

1 Do  1 All Do A, D

2  5  2 NA Do D

3 1  3 NA NA np.nan

4 Do  Do  Do  Do A, B, C, D
```

This is just an example, rows can be more than 1000.
I want a very effcient way, can't use apply as it would take long. (Columns and rows are dynamic, meaning column can be 10 and rows can be 1000).

Comment: post your coding efforts

Comment: Please explain better your expected output. What do you mean by "column name row wise"?

Comment: @gtomer please check second dataframe that is the output with Column_names which is expected

Answer (score 3):

With matrix product and strings concatenation:

```
df["Column Names"] = df.eq('Do').dot(df.columns).str.join(', ')
```

---

```
    A   B    C    D Column Names
0  Do   1  All   Do         A, D
1   5   2  NaN   Do            D
2   1   3  NaN  NaN             
3  Do  Do   Do   Do   A, B, C, D
```

Comment: it doesn't work for me, let's say column name is name1, name2. This it is giving n,a,m,e,1,n,a,m,e,2

Comment: I was able to do it : list(df.ne('Do').dot(df.columns + ', ')).str.replace(', ,', '').str.rstrip(',').
As per my requirements.

Comment: @sadaa, just apply `df.eq('Do').dot(df.columns + ', ').str.rstrip(', ')`

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use apply you can use `@` operator (but I'd prefer more `.apply` version):

```py
c = df.columns + "|"  # I'm supposing column names don't contain `|` character

df["Column Names"] = (
    ((df == "Do") @ c).str.split("|").str[:-1].str.join(", ").replace("", np.nan)
)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    A   B    C    D Column Names
0  Do   1  All   Do         A, D
1   5   2  NaN   Do            D
2   1   3  NaN  NaN          NaN
3  Do  Do   Do   Do   A, B, C, D
```

---

EDIT:

With dataframe:

```
  Name1 Name2 Name3 Name4
1    Do     1   All    Do
2     5     2   NaN    Do
3     1     3   NaN   NaN
4    Do    Do    Do    Do
```

Running:

```py
c = df.columns + "|"  # I'm supposing column names don't contain `|` character

df["Column Names"] = (
    ((df == "Do") @ c).str.split("|").str[:-1].str.join(", ").replace("", np.nan)
)

print(df)
```

I get:

```
  Name1 Name2 Name3 Name4                Column Names
1    Do     1   All    Do                Name1, Name4
2     5     2   NaN    Do                       Name4
3     1     3   NaN   NaN                         NaN
4    Do    Do    Do    Do  Name1, Name2, Name3, Name4
```

Comment: it doesn't work for me, let's say column name is name1, name2. This it is giving n,a,m,e,1,n,a,m,e,2 .

Comment: @sadaa With column names `name1`, `name2`, `name3` and `name4` I get expected result (see my edit).